# Selenium Equivalent of networkidle2/networkIdle0 in Puppeteer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, puppeteer

Puppeteer has "networkIdle0" (0 network connections for 500ms) and "networkIdle2" (no more than 2 network connections for 500ms). How can I achieve the same using selenium? How can I check for active network connections in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

You should use proper wait strategy to achieve the same result.

Comment: Is there a way to get access to the network connection?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the ruby solution to achieve that, which will give you a good idea what to wait for

```js
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
wait.until {
    @driver.execute_script("return document.readyState;") == "complete" 
}
```

Comment: document.readyState will show complete only when the page load is completed, right. I am looking for a specific scenario when there is no network activity for a specific period of time.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work reliably for SPAs. We've got an Angular app that loads hundreds of images, and readyState == "complete" when none of them are are actually loaded. Instead, we wait until one of our loaded elements is visible, in  like:

```lang-python

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
...
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=15).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.isotope-asset")))
```